# how does tr (unix translate) handle ne line?

Tags: newline, tr

I have been noticing behaviour with end of line '\n' I don't understand and therefore I have come up with the following "test".  I am on Mac OS X.

I have a file with:

```
one two
three four five
six seven
```

Then I run

```
x=$(awk '{print}' filename.txt)
```

and

```
echo "$x"
```

prints correctly (i.e. the content of the file as above).

However, when I do

```
y=$(echo $x | tr "\n" "N")
```

(I do mean to translate new line '\n' into a capital 'N', just to see what happens), then I get

```
one two three four five six sevenN
```

It seems that all occurrences of '\n', but the last, are detected (because the output is on one line) but not replaced with 'N', while the replacement occurs for the last instance.

Is the last character (at the end of the file) different from the other new line characters?

I don't understand what is going on.

**EDIT**

I can think of one difference between the last line and the others.  `awk` sees one new line character `\n` at the end of all lines except the last one, and when it prints it adds another one such new line.  So what I need is to replace a *double* new line with `N`.

On the other hand, why do I not see **two** `N`s?

There is only one '\n' at the end of the last line, and it is replaced with `N`.

Is this getting closer to an explanation?

Comment: the commands as pasted here work for me on mac. Can you try in a new terminal to make sure there is nothing intefering?

Comment: The difference is that you didn't quote the `$x` variable. Write `y=$(echo "$x" | tr "\n" "N")` instead. The `"`s around `$x` are not for decoration.

Comment: @mosvy ah yes, the quotes...  and yet I had been warned!  So now, _with_ the quotes the commands work as expected.  I still be happy to understand why it was doing what it did with the missing quotes - but that's not so critical now.

Comment: @Antoine [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05). after which pathname expansion (globbing) will be done too -- eg. if you had '*' instead of 'three' in your file, it will be replaced with the filenames from the current directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

```
x=$(awk '{print}' filename.txt)
y=$(echo $x | tr "\n" "N")
```

In your example code, `${x}` is assigned the contents of `filename.txt` including newlines (\n).

For the assignment of `${y}` you echo variable `x`. In this case echo will remove \n inside `x` and append one at the end of the line. That is piped to `tr`. So it converts the one \n it sees to an N.

If you use `echo`, the line will be terminated with a \n. Should you use `printf`, the line may not be terminated with a \n. In that case `awk` will add an additional \n for the last line. In rare cases, this would have the output not match the input.

### Credits

Mosvy was first to notice you needed to quote x, for example `echo "${x}" | tr` to retain the \n inside x.
RARE Kpop Manifesto noticed the rare case of input not matching output.

Answer (score 0):

the trailing `%` is to indicate it lacks trailing `\n` :

> ```
> mawk 'FS = "^$"' RS='\r?\n' ORS='N'
> ```

```
one twoNthree four fiveNsix sevenN%
```

skip the `RS` part if u don't need to account for Windows/DOS sources, and make it ultra succinct :

> ```
> nawk 'ORS = "N"'
> ```

if u want it with trailing `\n`, and input isn't gigantic :

> ```
> gawk 'BEGIN { RS="^$"; FS="\r?\n"; OFS="N" } NF=NF'
> ```

```
one twoNthree four fiveNsix sevenN
```